# java compiling error in command prompt

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Error: Main method not found in class volume, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

```
import java.util.*;
class volume {

    private int x;

    public float volume(float l) {
    return (l * l * l);
    }

    public float volume(float r, float h) {
    return (3.14f * r * r * h);
    }

    public float volume(float l, float b, float h) {
    return (l * b * h);
    }
}

class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    volume a = new volume();
    System.out.println("volume of cube=" + a.volume(10));
    System.out.println("volume of cylinder=" + a.volume(10, 10));
    System.out.println("volume of cuboid=" + a.volume(10, 10, 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: By convention, Java class names should start with a capital letter. You should rename class ``volume`` to ``Volume`` and class ``main`` to ``Main``.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `main` method to `volume` class and make `volume` class public. You don't need `class main`.

Answer (score 0):

remove class main { and } then you will have a main method in Volume class

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine. you just compile the `main` class and execute the `main` class.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, the main method should be inside the class Volume. In spite of that, your code should have worked. But the real reason you are getting the error is because remember: in Java, the class names have to start with an uppercase.

Simply rename the class volume as Volume, and main as Main and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your public class in your program. Then everything works fine.